# LaTex-Table (automated linebreak for long text)

Tags: tables, tabularray

What have I to change in this table, that the long text ("Anmerkungen") will fit in the (merged) cells (automated linebreak)? It works in the row above,

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

```
\definecolor{grau}{RGB}{229,229,229}
\begin{textblock}{285}(5,25)    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{           
                width=1\linewidth,
                colspec={|X[1,1,halign=c]|X[2,2,halign=c]|X[3,2,halign=c]|X[4,2,halign=c]|},        
                cell{3}{1} = {valign=m},
                row{1} = {grau,halign=c},   
                column{1} = {grau},                 
                }
                \hline
                \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{TITLE}} \\
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{aktuelles Quartal}
                \hline
                  & A & B & C \\
                \hline
                 &  Grafik  & Grafik & Grafik \\
                \hline
                Zeitverlauf &  Grafik & it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works   & Grafik \\
                \hline          
                Anmerkungen & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{it doesnt work it doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt work it doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt work} \\                           
                \hline              
                \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{}} \\              
                \hline
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{textblock}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your table. For image use an `example-image` which is available to all of us.

Comment: Hello. I deleted the Image already. What elso do you need (sorry, ist my second day with laTex) ;(

Comment: A complete small document beginning with `\documentclass`, following gy preamble with all to your problem relevant packages, document body with your table and ending with `\end{document}. ><You should replace your original image wit `example-image` which are provided by `graphicx` package and are available to all of us. BTW, your table code is unacceptable mix of "classic" and `tabularray` syntax. Wit new version of `tabularray` will not be allowed anymore ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guessing, that you looking for something like this:

[image]

- In your table code you have a mess of syntax of "classic" table packages (as are for example `tabularx` and others) and `tabularray` which will in new coming realize will not tolerate such mix anymore. I strongly suggest you to use only `tabularray` syntax
- in "Anmerkungen" row you use `\multicolumn{3}{c}{...}` which not enable to break its contain to multi line text.
- Instead you should use `\SetCell[c=3]{<width>}` where width is equal to sum of by it spanned columns.

Possible solution is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{grau}{RGB}{229,229,229}
%\begin{textblock}{285}(5,25)
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                width=1\linewidth,
                hlines, vlines,
                colspec={ X[1.5,c,m] X[c] X[2,j,m] X[2,j,m] },
                cell{3}{1} = {m},
                row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=grau,c},
                column{1} = {bg=grau},
                }
                \SetCell[c=4]{c}    TITLE   
                    &  &   &   \\
                \SetCell[r=2]{c}    aktuelles Quartal
                    & A & B & C \\
                    &  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-duck}   
                        & Grafik 2 
                            & Grafik 3 \\
                Zeitverlauf 
                    &  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-duck}
                        & it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works
                            & Grafik 6 \\
                Anmerkungen 
                    & \SetCell[c=3]{j,m,0.75\linewidth} it doesnt work it doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt work it doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt work
                        &   &   \\
                \SetCell[c=4]{c} 
                    &   &   &   \\
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
%\end{textblock} 
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
With use of the`\adjincludegraphics˙ defined in` adjustbox` package the code for inserting  of images is a wee bit shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{grau}{RGB}{229,229,229}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth,
              valign=m}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[1.5,c,m, bg=grau] 
                        X[c] X[2,j,m] X[2,j,m]},
             cell{1}{1} = {c=4}{font=\bfseries, bg=grau, c},
             hspan=minimal
             }
    TITLE
        &  &   &   \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{c}    aktuelles Quartal
        & A & B & C \\
        &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
            & Grafik 2
                & Grafik 3 \\
    Zeitverlauf
        &  \adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck}
            & it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works
                & Grafik 6 \\
    Anmerkungen
        & \SetCell[c=3]{j,m} now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works now it works
        &   &   \\
\end{tblr}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: PERFECT. Thank you! Thats exactly what I want ;) I know, my code was a "mess" of google-search-copy-paste-try-error-despair.

Answer (score 7):

With a combination of `\SetCell` and `hspan=minimal` there is no need to manually determine the required width of the spanning cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{grau}{RGB}{229,229,229}    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{           
                width=1\linewidth,
                colspec={|X[1,1,halign=c]|X[2,2,halign=c]|X[3,2,halign=c]|X[4,2,halign=c]|},        
                cell{3}{1} = {valign=m},
                row{1} = {grau,halign=c},   
                column{1} = {grau},
                hspan=minimal         %<--------------- added        
                }
                \hline
                \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{TITLE}} \\
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{aktuelles Quartal}
                \hline
                  & A & B & C \\
                \hline
                 &  Grafik  & Grafik & Grafik \\
                \hline
                Zeitverlauf &  Grafik & it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works it works   & Grafik \\
                \hline          
                Anmerkungen & \SetCell[c=3]{j}it doesnt work it doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt work it doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt workit doesnt work \\                           % <-------------- \SetCell instead of \multicolumn 
                \hline              
                \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{}} \\              
                \hline
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for `hspan`,  I forgot on it :-(