# How to split longtable cell and adjust width fix with image width

Tags: longtable, multicolumn, split

I am trying to draw a long answer table containing image.
[image]

My effort is multicolumn and split the cell in to small table.
I can not adjust the width of small table with the image's width.
My MWE, please help me!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, a4paper]{geometry}  
\usepackage{longtable,tikz,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|p{0.7\linewidth}|p{0.1\linewidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{Ex} & \textbf{Ideas} & \textbf{Answer} & \textbf{Mark}\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{1}}& a) & Answer one & \textbf{1,0} \\
\cline{2-4}
& b) &
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.3\linewidth}l}
    \parbox{0.4\linewidth}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (2.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}}&
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.4\linewidth}|p{0.1\linewidth}@{}|}
    Answer 2 &0.25\\
    \hline
    Answer 3 &0.25\\
    \hline
    Answer 4 &0.25\\
    \hline
    Answer 5 &0.25\\
    \hline\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular}
}\\
\hline
 & c)& Answer 6 & 1.0\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't split cells, but you can merge them. One option is that in this cell you insert small table, another (somehow simpler) that you define one column more and merge adjacent cells where you like to have "one column" . See, if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632986/latex-table-automated-linebreak-for-long-text/632988#632988` can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

Based on answers on [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632986/latex-table-automated-linebreak-for-long-text/):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[hmargin={2cm,1.5cm}, vmargin=2cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}% 
                \bfseries}                          %

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead, middlehead, lasthead}{default}{} % <---
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{\scriptsize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
%
\sisetup{detect-weight, % <--
         mode=text,     % <--
         table-format=1.2}
\begin{longtblr}{hlines, vlines,
        rowhead = {1},
        colspec = {Q[c,font=\bfseries] 
                   Q[c,m] 
                   X[1.2, l] X[0.8, h, j] Q[h, c, si]},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        hspan=minimal
                }
Ex  & Ideas & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  Answer               
                        &           &   Mark    \\
\SetCell[r=6]{h}    1
    & a)    & \SetCell[c=2]{j} 
              Answer 1  \lipsum[66] 
                        &           &\B 1.0     \\
    & \SetCell[r=4]{c} b)    
            & \SetCell[r=4]{c}    
                \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \draw (0,0) circle (2.5);
                \end{tikzpicture}%    
                        & Answer 2  &   0.25    \\
    &       &           & Answer 3  &   0.25    \\
    &       &           & Answer 4  &   0.25    \\
    &       &           & {Answer 5\\  \lipsum[1][1-2]}
                                    &   0.25    \\
    & c)    & \SetCell[c=2]{j}
              Answer 6  \lipsum[66]
                        &           &\B 1.0     \\
\end{longtblr}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will study this code. Thank you very much!